# Wiring hard start kit to compressor

Tags: capacitor, ac, induction-motor

First of all, I am not sure if this is something for electrical engineering or home improvement, therefore feel free to flag it as wrong community if you disagree with my choice.

Now, I am trying to give my generator a fighting chance to start my 2 cylinder air compressor and not stall on the start current. I bought a hard start kit that matches the voltage of my air compressor. Now the problem is that in my country people dont usually tinker with their tools, you buy it and you throw it away at the first sign of an error. The consequence is that things have no meaningful description...

I am currently trying to figure out how to wire the hard start kit. According to the description it needs to be wired in parallel with the run capacitor. I have opened up the electronics of my compressor and found two capacitors (which is expected in my opinion, a start and a run capacitor). However unfortunately they are not labelled and neither is the "board" they are connected to. So I have to go with the values to determine which one is the run capacitor. Below is an image of the wiring:

[image]

I've tried to determine what capacitor I need to wire my hard start kit to. Some google research showed that normally the start capacitor has a much higher capacitance than the run capacitor, so this would indicate that the blue capacitor is the start capacitor and the white one is the run capacitor. This again means that my kit needs to be wired to the white capacitor. However my kit is rated for a range from 115V to 250V, so I feel like adding it to the 450V capacitor is not a good idea.

I would therefore appreciate some guidance on how to wire this.

Comment: Absolutely no issues with too high voltage rating on the capacitor!

Comment: How about a soft start? I have built several in order to not bog down generators, although not for a compressor.

Comment: A soft start kit does look interesting indeed, and no question about wiring there